# Glide is not loading image from firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on a firebase project but I am facing a problem like when I upload an image on firebase I am not getting it in my original apk. I upload an image on firebase and save its URL in the firebase database and then when I load it with the Recycler view and Glide library it stuck on the placeholder image but did not load the original image. Can anyone help me to solve this problem I provided my source code below:-

EventActivity:-

```
public class EventActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private ImageAdapter imageAdapter;

    private DatabaseReference mDatabaseRef;

    private List<Upload> mUploads;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_event);

        mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("NotifyImages");


        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        mUploads = new ArrayList<>();

        mDatabaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Upload upload = postSnapshot.getValue(Upload.class);
                    mUploads.add(upload);
                }

                imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(EventActivity.this, mUploads);
                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Upload class:-

```
public class Upload {
    private String mName;
    private String mImageUri;

    public Upload() {
    }

    public Upload(String name, String ImageUri) {
        if (name.trim().equals("")) {
            name = "No name";

        }


        mName = name
        ;
        mImageUri = ImageUri;

    }

    public String getName() {
        return mName;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        mName = name;
    }

    public String getImageUri() {
        return mImageUri;
    }

    public void setImageUri(String ImageUri) {
        mImageUri = ImageUri;
    }

}
```

Image Adapter:-

```
public class ImageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageAdapter.ImageViewHolder> {


    private Context mContext;
    private List<Upload> mUploads;

    public ImageAdapter(Context context, List<Upload> uploads) {
        mContext = context;
        mUploads = uploads;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ImageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.image_item, parent, false);
        return new ImageViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ImageViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Upload uploadCurrent = mUploads.get(position);
        holder.textViewName.setText(uploadCurrent.getName());
//        Glide.with(mContext)
//                .load(uploadCurrent.getImageUri())
//                .centerCrop()
//                .into(holder.imageView);

        Glide.with(mContext)
                .load(uploadCurrent.getImageUri())
                .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
                .centerCrop()
                .into(holder.imageView);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mUploads.size();
    }

    public class ImageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView textViewName;
        public ImageView imageView;

        public ImageViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            textViewName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_name);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_upload);

        }
    }
}
```

activity_event.xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

ImageItem.xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffff">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textColor="@color/ColorRed"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_upload"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"


            />

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

You can easily copy my code and test it. Please answer me if you find a solution.

Comment: are you sure that image link is working and please post the error log your getting.

Comment: Can you show the code for `save its URL in the firebase`

Comment: bro logcat is not showing any error and i am sure that my image link working properly

Comment: @TakeInfos what do you mean? which code do you want?

Comment: @Ashish here is an url of an image https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/themusicapp-50ba2.appspot.com/o/Uploads%2F4315345345.jpg%2F1566642086712.jpg?alt=media&token=a275ffca-cee2-45cd-89a3-e583bd54a8bf

Comment: @HunnyArora please log `uploadCurrent.getImageUri()` in `onBindViewholder`. So we can check if your array contains the url or not

Comment: @Ashish can you tell me how can i log that?

Comment: `Log.e("uri", uploadCurrent.getImageUri());` put this in onBindViewholder

Comment: Yes I have done it and it shows as many red lines in logcat now what can i do

Comment: Please post those line in your question. Does it contains similar url your looking for ?

Comment: 2019-08-28 15:35:44.258 18861-18861/com.geetmp3.themusicapp E/uri: com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@5c6b40
2019-08-28 15:35:44.455 18861-18861/com.geetmp3.themusicapp E/uri: com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@bed4b0e
2019-08-28 15:35:44.954 18861-18861/com.geetmp3.themusicapp E/uri: com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@3a0de13

Comment: @HunnyArora Please post your database screenshot cause it only provide you taskid.

Comment: @Ashish https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZJsZgyVgRw_VaRyGAf6L7DEK6tN0WUi3/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @HunnyArora the problem isn't with your code. It is problem with how you put the image url in database. It is not the imageurl.

Comment: @Ashish please sir can you tell me how to solve this problem?

Comment: Please post your code to store the imageurl in database.

Comment: But sir  I posted all code above. can you tell me which more code do you want?

Comment: @HunnyArora Code which stores the value to database.

Comment: Ohh ok I have done this process in another apk please wait a moment I am sending you code

Comment: @Ashish https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uCmszCujn6l0FZxDFvAPRZ9zRtgpzLmg/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make changes in your `UploadFile()` Function :

```
fireRef.putFile(ImageUri)
    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                }
            } , 5000);

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Upload Successfull", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Task<Uri> urlTask = taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl();
            while (!urlTask.isSuccessful());
            Uri downloadUrl = urlTask.getResult();
            Upload upload = new Upload(mainEditTextNotify.getText().toString().trim(),
                    downloadUrl.toString());
            String uploadId = mDataRef.push().getKey();
            mDataRef.child(uploadId).setValue(upload);

        }
    })
```

The above code will provide you proper uri of image which you can store inside Database.

It will provide you proper uri which will help to load images in Glide.

But i suggest to store filepath from Firebase Storage. Cause if uri token expires then you need generate uri token and change with old one.